# Вывод шаблона в браузер

Tags: шаблоны, php, mvc

Пишу мини-фреймворк для сайта. Есть файл view.php со след содержанием:

```
class View
{
    public function render($template)
    {
        ob_start();
        include VIEWS . $template . EXT;
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
}
```

В контроллерах обращаюсь к методу render следующий образом

```
class IndexController extends Controller
{
    function indexAction()
    {
        $view = new View();
        $view->render('index');
    }
}
```

Без буферизации в методе render на экран выводится содержимое шаблона, а с буферизацией нет. Как поступить, чтобы все было грамотно? Спасибо!

Нашел в сети след. пример

```
public function render($viewName, $controllerName)
{
    $layout = 'layouts' . DS.     $this->_layout . '.php';

    ob_start();     
        include $view;
        $content = ob_get_clean();
    include $layout;        
}
```

Есть ли смысл в буферизации, если в конце метода render идет инклюд базового шаблона после остановки буферизации?

Comment: @vinnie, $view->render **возвращает** шаблон, поэтому он и не выводится. В результате буферизации полученное содержимое уйдет как возвращаемое значение $view->render(), которое игнорируется, т.к. не участвует в выражении и не присваивается переменной. Простое `echo $view->render('index');` должно все вывести, как и полагается.

Comment: @vinnie

> будет ли это правильным с точки зрения mvc?

Зависит только от архитектуры. В симфони/джанго, например, контроллер возвращает *ответ*, в котором есть *тело*, а выводит это тело уже само приложение, например. В Yii не парятся и выводят самой вьюхой или контроллером, в зависимости от предпочтений.

> И где лучше всего подключить базовую разметку сайта?

обычно есть layout, общий шаблон или базовая разметка, в середине которого торчит `echo $content`. `$content` же - это как раз вывод одного конкретного шаблона.
Вообще конкретно по этой теме посмотрите Twig и как его используют.

Comment: И все же было бы здорово, если бы кто-нить подсказал, где лучше всего определять базовый шаблон и выводить его ((

Comment: @vinnie, я выше написал про лейаут. Он просто валяется в папке с шаблонами и представляет собой шаблон, внутри которого вставляется рендер другого. Или, в толковых системах, от него наследуются остальные шаблоны.

Answer (score 1):

Вы собрались передавать только название файла-представления? А данные для вывода?
Учтите необходимость иногда не выводить содержимое, а только возвращать HTML-код.
Так же иногда нужно обрабатывать предварительно результат (имеется ввиду одиночные случаи относительно общих параметров вывода), например смена кодировки, обрезание спец. символов и т.д., для чкго полезно было бы добавить во входящие параметры callback